# Make an element change colour over time that is only visible when the element is hovered, but independent of the hover itself

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

This hypothetical button would be yellow when it isn't hovered, but would be a different colour depending on what time you do hover over it.  So the animation would be persistent whether or not it is being hovered and if you never hovered it, you would never know the colour on hover is changing because it would always be yellow otherwise.

I hope this explanation makes sense.  I haven't got any code to offer, because if it is doable I have no idea where I would start.

EDIT:

HTML

```
<div class = "box"></div>
<button class = "btn">Colour change animation</button>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  margin : 50px;
  height  :200px;
  width  : 200px;
  background-color : pink;
}

.colour-changer:hover {
  animation : colour-change 5s linear 0s;
}

@keyframes colour-change {

  0% {
  }

  100% {
    background-color : purple;
  }

}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].classList.add("colour-changer"); 
  });
});
```

I did try to make a JSFiddle, but I couldn't get it working for some reason.

Anyway, this makes the box change colour after the class is added and you also hover the box and the animation restarts every time you hover the box.  What I'm after is making the animation happen regardless of the hover, but only be visible when hovered so the box would otherwise be pink.

Comment: Why would someone do something like this. Seems quite useless. A more reasonable approach is changing the color when it's hovered. No point changing the color if none can see it. The basic purpose of a color is to be seen.

Comment: The idea is the colour would be different every time you hover depending on how far along the animation is as opposed to never seeing it.  I hope that makes better sense.

Comment: Then you can keep track of what color would be displayed based on the time elapsed, but you don't actually have to "animate" the color when it isn't shown.

Comment: The colour would ideally be going smoothly from one to the other, so I wouldn't know what the exact colour code is at a given time.  Unless there is a way of getting that information constantly?

Comment: You can't do this with keyframes. What this sounds like is you need a transition and set the initial bg color from time to time.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea.  This won't work for me in particular, because I wanted to sync the colour with another colour change keyframes animation that must be pausable.  The only way I know of doing that is with animation-play-state.  However, I would happily accept an answer like this if I could, because I just wanted to know if it was possible to achieve this effect at all really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to use multiple background to have two layers. The top one always visible and with the same color and the bottom one will be animated continously and changing its color (we cannot see it of course). The on hover you make the first layer invisible and you pause the animation and we will see the new color.

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow), linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size: 0%, 100%;
  animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow), linear-gradient(red, red);
  }
  30% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow), linear-gradient(orange, orange);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow), linear-gradient(green, green);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is easily closest to my original goal and I especially like that it is a CSS answer too.  Very clever implementation, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a jquery solution, and with a bit of work it could be migrated to vanilla javascript.  Also, there's a 1/6 chance of no color change, but it should give you a sense of one way to go about doing this:

HTML:

```
<div class = "box"></div><button class = "btn">Colour change when hovered</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.color-0{
  background-color:purple !important;
}
.color-1{
  background-color:blue !important;
}
.color-2{
  background-color:green !important;
}
.color-3{
  background-color:yellow !important;
}
.color-4{
  background-color:orange !important;
}
.color-5{
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

Javascript (+ JQuery):

```
$("button").on("mouseenter",function(){
  $(this).removeClass("color-0");
  $(this).removeClass("color-1");
  $(this).removeClass("color-2");
  $(this).removeClass("color-3");
  $(this).removeClass("color-4");
  $(this).removeClass("color-5");
  var d = new Date();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();
  var color = parseInt(seconds % 6);
  $(this).addClass("color-"+color.toString());
})
```

example JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/needsmorejson/yL31cjtd/19/

Comment: This looks very promising!  I think I need to compromise my original idea somewhat, it is not worth the time expense to get what I'm after and this is a very nice middle ground indeed to base a similar idea on.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice JSfiddle. This matches the original question for time of day well